# Failed to create pod sandbox [flannel]

Tags: kubernetes, flannel

[image: Kube flannel DaemonSets]I am running into this error on random pods. Thank you @matthew-l-daniel for the comment - as I didn't know where to start. 
Here is the contents of /opt/cni/bin on the node

`:/opt/cni/bin$ ls
bridge  host-local  loopback`

Here are the kubelet logs for a container that failed.

`Jan 30 15:42:00 ip-172-20-39-216 kubelet[32233]: E0130 15:42:00.924370   32233 kuberuntime_sandbox.go:54] CreatePodSandbox for pod "postgres-core-0_service-master-459cf23(d8acae2f-24a2-11e9-b79c-0a0d1213cce2)" failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to start sandbox container for pod "postgres-core-0": Error response from daemon: grpc: the connection is unavailable
Jan 30 15:42:00 ip-172-20-39-216 kubelet[32233]: E0130 15:42:00.924380   32233 kuberuntime_manager.go:647] createPodSandbox for pod "postgres-core-0_service-master-459cf23(d8acae2f-24a2-11e9-b79c-0a0d1213cce2)" failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to start sandbox container for pod "postgres-core-0": Error response from daemon: grpc: the connection is unavailable 
Jan 30 15:42:00 ip-172-20-39-216 kubelet[32233]: E0130 15:42:00.924427   32233 pod_workers.go:186] Error syncing pod d8acae2f-24a2-11e9-b79c-0a0d1213cce2 ("postgres-core-0_service-master-459cf23(d8acae2f-24a2-11e9-b79c-0a0d1213cce2)"), skipping: failed to "CreatePodSandbox" for "postgres-core-0_service-master-459cf23(d8acae2f-24a2-11e9-b79c-0a0d1213cce2)" with CreatePodSandboxError: "CreatePodSandbox for pod \"postgres-core-0_service-master-459cf23(d8acae2f-24a2-11e9-b79c-0a0d1213cce2)\" failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to start sandbox container for pod \"postgres-core-0\": Error response from daemon: grpc: the connection is unavailable"`

As for flannel container logs, there are many flannel pods running - and all are healthy.

1. Kubernetes v 1.10.11
2. Docker version 17.03.2-ce, build f5ec1e2

**Flannel logs**

`E0130 15:34:16.536354       1 vxlan_network.go:187] DelFDB failed: no such file or directory
E0130 15:34:16.536411       1 vxlan_network.go:191] failed to delete vxlanRoute (100.107.178.0/24 -> 100.107.178.0): no such process
E0130 17:33:44.848163       1 vxlan_network.go:187] DelFDB failed: no such file or directory
E0130 17:33:44.848219       1 vxlan_network.go:191] failed to delete vxlanRoute (100.107.201.0/24 -> 100.107.201.0): no such process`

Comment: Without the logs from your flannel container, or the logs from kubelet, or knowing if you have `/opt/cni/bin` populated correctly, there is no way we can help you. And restarting kubelet will definitely not fix any CNI problems -- kubelet is merely a consumer of CNI

Comment: So, yes, it certainly appears that the flannel CNI plugin is not installed; you may have success with their [DaemonSet](https://github.com/coreos/flannel/blob/v0.11.0/Documentation/k8s-manifests/kube-flannel-legacy.yml) -- or revisit the install instructions for your cluster and see if you missed the flannel step

Comment: Silly question - if its CNI plugin not installed - why would this fail randomly , and that too for some pods ? This should be a cluster wide issue - no?

Comment: "This should be a cluster wide issue - no?" no, because not every Pod in the cluster uses the SDN; some are `hostNetwork: true` and thus skip the interaction with CNI entirely

Comment: "This cluster was created using kops" then I don't know what to tell you, as I avoid those binary-do-magic deployment toys like the plague for _this very reason_; try changing the tags and subject of your question to say that kops misdeployed your flannel and see if any kops wizards have insight

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel im going to follow your suggestion. One more question. How would I verify /test that I have correctly installed the plugin.

Comment: `kubectl run --image=busybox -- sleep 120` and observe that it has a `.status.podIP` within your flannel subnet is the best answer I have for you, aside from the lack of error messages in the flannel pods